# How to use local libs in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I import local libs in python3?

**setup.cfg**

```
[install]
prefix=./
```

**requirements.txt**

```
# cat requirements.txt 
docopt==0.6.2
```

**test.py**

```
"""
Usage:
  test.py facility-list

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('Hellow World')
```

**shell**

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from docopt import docopt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
```

Why wont the import work? After the pip2 install I have a `./lib` folder in my project folder.

Comment: Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) instead.

Comment: [`python3 -m venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 allows you to easily use a virtual environment. In fact it's a built in feature nowadays.

Go to the folder with your project and type in

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
```

And it'll create a folder called myvenv. The next step is to activate the virtualenv with the following command.

```
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

You're now running inside the virtual environment and can do a pip install.